# Prevent Restart after Updates

Tags: updates, update-manager

I find it a bit annoying that Ubuntu (in my case: 14.04 LTS) wants to restart quite often after updates, and therefore I want to supress this updates and only start them manually. Since I use the computer regularly, I want normal updates to take place as usual. Is there a way to do so?

As [Why does Ubuntu need to reboot so often?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32098/why-does-ubuntu-need-to-reboot-so-often) suggests, kernel package updates and some other (unkown) updates force a reboot. Is it possible to disable (all) those updates in the update-manager?

[How can I stop the Software Updater from nagging me to restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403413/how-can-i-stop-the-software-updater-from-nagging-me-to-restart) suggests disabling the update-manager at all, but since I want to get regular updates, this is not suitable for me. The other suggested way of this post is to supress the warnings via dconf editor. I assume that the updates are there for some reason and therefore should not be disabled.

So all in all - is there a way to prevent updates that force restarts (and still allow other updates), or to ad-hoc install all updates without restart in Ubuntu? KSplice (http://www.ksplice.com/) seems to have the feature with the ad-hoc installation.

Only using the update-manager is not enough: For example the current update saying it upgrades:

```
  firefox firefox-locale-de firefox-locale-en libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26
  libgnutls26:i386
```

caused an UI popup telling me that a computer restart is required. No kernel updates was included. Is there some way of preventing this required reboot? What happens if I refuse to reboot, may I have security problems (because of the old OpenSSL-version)?

Comment: If the kernel is updated you have to reboot, you could disable `update-manager` and run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to update the system.

Comment: Learn to use `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` in command line. These two commands won't ask to reboot because they are aimed more at advanced user, those who know what they're doing

Comment: @Serg: Unfortunately, this is not true. If I run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade, I sometimes get an UI notification that a restart is required. I'll add an example for the update today, where this happens.